# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode

Tags: web3js, testrpc, crowdsale

I'm testing out the crowdsale contract from https://ethereum.org/crowdsale on a local testrpc and I can't figure out how to send funds to it. As I understand it, the anonymous fallback function receives the funds send to the contract. The `sendTransaction` method is not available directly on the contract instance, so I've tried out a few other options (and read the docs and done loads of googling).

Any suggestions?

Here's the javascript:

```
const cl = console.log; cl; // avoid lint error
// const Web3 = require("web3");

if (typeof global.web3 !== 'undefined') {
  global.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  global.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}

const web3 = global.web3;
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

var ifSuccessfulSendTo = web3.eth.accounts[1] /* var of type address here */ ;
var fundingGoalInEthers = 20 /* var of type uint256 here */ ;
var durationInMinutes = 10 /* var of type uint256 here */ ;
var etherCostOfEachToken = 0.2 /* var of type uint256 here */ ;
var addressOfTokenUsedAsReward = web3.eth.accounts[2] /* var of type address here */ ;

var browser_cs_sol_crowdsaleContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"checkGoalReached","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"deadline","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"beneficiary","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"tokenReward","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"fundingGoal","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"amountRaised","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"price","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"safeWithdrawal","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"ifSuccessfulSendTo","type":"address"},{"name":"fundingGoalInEthers","type":"uint256"},{"name":"durationInMinutes","type":"uint256"},{"name":"etherCostOfEachToken","type":"uint256"},{"name":"addressOfTokenUsedAsReward","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"totalAmountRaised","type":"uint256"}],"name":"GoalReached","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"backer","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"isContribution","type":"bool"}],"name":"FundTransfer","type":"event"}]);
var browser_cs_sol_crowdsale = browser_cs_sol_crowdsaleContract.new(
   ifSuccessfulSendTo,
   fundingGoalInEthers,
   durationInMinutes,
   etherCostOfEachToken,
   addressOfTokenUsedAsReward,
   {
     from: web3.eth.defaultAccount, 
     // from: web3.eth.accounts[3], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    // console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })

// cl('browser_cs_sol_crowdsale',browser_cs_sol_crowdsale)
const contract = global.contract = browser_cs_sol_crowdsale;

global.go = ()=>{

  const params = {
     from: web3.eth.defaultAccount
     // from: web3.eth.accounts[5]
    ,to: contract.address
    ,value: web3.fromDecimal(20)
    // ,value: 10
    ,gas: 1000000
  };
  cl('params',params);
  // contract.beneficiary.sendTransaction( params, function(err, txHash) {
  web3.eth.sendTransaction( params, function(err, txHash) {
    if (err != null) {
     cl("Error while sending transaction: " + err);
    } else {
     cl("Transaction sent, here's your txHash: " + txHash);
    }
  });

}; // go

module.exports = web3;
```

Which produces this error when running `go()` from the console:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
```

Here's the acutal contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;
// https://ethereum.org/crowdsale

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount);
}

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public deadline;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    function Crowdsale(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function () payable {
        require(!crowdsaleClosed);
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /**
     * Check if goal was reached
     *
     * Checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign
     */
    function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    /**
     * Withdraw the funds
     *
     * Checks to see if goal or time limit has been reached, and if so, and the funding goal was reached,
     * sends the entire amount to the beneficiary. If goal was not reached, each contributor can withdraw
     * the amount they contributed.
     */
    function safeWithdrawal() afterDeadline {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems could be that you are setting tokenReward (the address of the token you will be using for distribution) to be one of the eth accounts, which is an externally owned account (a user).
The crowdsale contract requires that you first deploy the token contract, take note of it's address and that's the address you have to pass to the crowdsale constructor.

This surely makes it fail when you try to execute the token.transfer() function on said address.

I recommend you try all this on Remix instead of web3 so you can debug it easily and call each contract's functions without having to write further code.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I am completely new to Ethereum and solidity - and I was hoping to just focus on the javascript bit by using a backend that already works out of the box. What you explain above is currently beyond my understanding of solidity.

Comment: Are you saying that I should first deploy the `interface token`, get its address and pass that address in to the Contract constructor - as which parameter? And how does Remix allow for passing in values in to the constructor?

Comment: I would recommend starting the other way around. First, because that example contract on Ethereum's site is nowhere close to being production ready, it's extremely far from perfect.
Second, if you don't understand what is happening on the Solidity code you won't know what parameters to supply from the front-end.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions where to start?

Comment: The op is right, you are using an EOA (`web3.eth.accounts[2] `) as the token address. But this must be a valid (ERC20) Token which is deployed before the crowdsale smart contract. Probably go through the Token example on the site and then go to crowdsale sample again. The interface `token` is used so you can call the `transfer(...)` function on the ERC20-Token you deployed before. The first arguments of `transfer(...)` should then be the target account you want to transfer Tokens to.